# rbind/data.frame conversion type hierarchy R

Tags: r, matrix, type-conversion, dataframe

Could anyone systematically explain to me the hierarchy of type conversion between character/numeric/factor while using rbind and data.frame?

In my understanding, `rbind` puts together in a matrix, which can only have one type. So if there's a type conflict, what's the type that will get converted to? Do other types of matrix-creation function (e.g. `cbind`, `matrix`) work the same way? Example:

```
> sapply(rbind("a", "b"), class)
      a           b 
"character" "character" 
> sapply(rbind(1, "b"), class)
          1           b 
"character" "character"
```

On the other hand, a data frame can hold multiple types, so `data.frame` preserves the original type, EXCEPT that it always tries to convert character into factors. (Is this correct? This is very counter-intuitive to me.)

With the same logic, is it correct that a factor type will always remain factor, no matter whether it is `factor(c(1,2))` or `factor(c("a", "b"))`?

```
> sapply(data.frame("a", "b"), class)
    X.a.     X.b. 
"factor" "factor" 
> sapply(data.frame(1, "b"), class)
       X1      X.b. 
"numeric"  "factor"
> sapply(data.frame(1, factor("a")), class)
     X1 factor..a.. 
  "numeric"    "factor"
```

Comment: see the argument `stringsAsFactors` in `data.frame` or in your global options.

Comment: I know there's such a thing. I'm asking for a systematic explanation of what type has priority in conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the **Value** section of `?cbind` (or `?rbind`):

"The type of a matrix result determined from the highest type of any of the inputs in the hierarchy raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list"

Some examples of coercion depending on the hierarchy:

```
# logical
a <- c(FALSE, TRUE)

# integer
b <- 0:1

# double
c <- c(0, 1.0)

# character
d <- c("0", "1")


m1 <- cbind(a, b)
m1
str(m1)
# logical converted to integer

m2 <- cbind(b, c)
m2
str(m2)
# integer converted to double

m3 <- cbind(c, d)
m3
str(m3)
# double converted to character
```

See also "**Data frame methods**" in `?cbind`.

Comment: Where is factor in that list?

Comment: Integer. Check `f1 <- factor(0:1)`; `f2 <- factor(c("0", "1"))`; `typeof(f1)`; `typeof(f2)`. See `?factor`: "an object of class "factor" which has a set of integer codes the length of x with a "levels" attribute of mode character".