# Custom sum function in dplyr returns inconsistent results

Tags: r, dplyr

I've made a custom sum function that ignores `NA`s unless all are `NA`. When I use it in `dplyr` it returns odd results and I don't know why.

```
require(dplyr)

dta <- data.frame(year=2007:2013, rrconf=c(79, NaN ,474,2792,1686,3313,3456), enrolled=c(NaN,NaN,458,1222,1155,1906,2184))

sum0 <- function(x, ...){
  # remove NAs unless all are NA
  if(is.na(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))) return(NA)
  else(sum(x, ..., na.rm=TRUE))
} 

dta %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(rrconf=sum0(rrconf), enrolled=sum0(enrolled))
```

gives me

```
Source: local data frame [7 x 3]

  year rrconf enrolled
1 2007     79       NA
2 2008     NA       NA
3 2009    474     TRUE
4 2010   2792     TRUE
5 2011   1686     TRUE
6 2012   3313     TRUE
7 2013   3456     TRUE
```

In this case it is only summing over one value, but in my bigger application in might summer over multiple values. Wrapping my `sum0` function in `as.integer()` seems to fix it, but I couldn't tell you why.

Is this the correct way to work around this problem? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1 magrittr_1.0.1 parallel_3.1.0 Rcpp_0.11.2    tools_3.1.0
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way to write the function but that line is meant to test whether all values are `NA`s. so `sum0(c(NA,3,NA))` returns 3, but `sum0(c(NA,NA,NA))` returns `NA`.

Comment: `sum(x, na.rm = ifelse(all(is.na(x)), FALSE, TRUE))` work?

Comment: There is slightly different behaviour between `mean` and `sum` when using `na.rm=T`. If all are `NA`, `mean` returns `NaN`, whereas `sum` returns 0.

Comment: @rawr how about `sum(x, na.rm = !all(is.na(x))`

Comment: @rawr and @Gregor, thank you that is much more elegant, but I still don't understand why `dplyr` keeps interpreting my column type as logical based on the first iteration. That's my real question. But I do appreciate your better code!

Comment: Perplexingly, I can make the code work if I run `dta$enrolled[1] <- 10` first, to ensure the first value processed is not `NaN`. This seems like a bug to me with `dplyr` assuming variable types. I can also make any column fail by making the first value `NaN`.

Comment: @Gregor nice but I try to keep raw emotions out of my code :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue seems to be with `dplyr` determining the column type in reference to the first returned result. If you force the `NA` value, which is by default a logical value, to be an `NA_real_` or `NA_integer_`, then you will be sorted:

```
##Just to show what NA normally does first:
class(NA)
#[1] "logical"

sum0 <- function(x, ...){
  # remove NAs unless all are NA
  if(is.na(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))) return(NA_real_)
  else(sum(x, ..., na.rm=TRUE))
} 

dta %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(rrconf=sum0(rrconf), enrolled=sum0(enrolled))

#Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
# 
#  year rrconf enrolled
#1 2007     79       NA
#2 2008     NA       NA
#3 2009    474      458
#4 2010   2792     1222
#5 2011   1686     1155
#6 2012   3313     1906
#7 2013   3456     2184
```

Comment: Thank you @thelatemail that makes sense. So normally functions returning `NA` do so in the "correct" `class`? Is that why this problem only occurs with my custom function? For example, I note that `class(sum(NA))` is `integer` not `logical`.

Comment: @Tom - yeah, it has to do with the hierarchy of different R object types. It's a bit confusing but maybe this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763355/rbind-data-frame-conversion-type-hierarchy-r I think this might be `dplyr` specific though as something like `class(c(NA,1))` is dealt with appropriately in base R.

Comment: For performance reasons, dplyr assumes that mutate results are "type stable" - i.e. the type of the first element is the type of all subsequent elements. One day we might be able to relax this restriction, but until then, just make sure your function returns results of a consistent type.

Comment: @hadley - could this be made somewhat more robust if it referenced the first non `NA` value? Not sure of the speed implications of that, but I can see this issue catching people out fairly regularly.

Comment: @thelatemail yes, there are ways to fix it, they're just not that high on the to do list currently.

Comment: I just ran into this problem today using rowwise addition, mutate and dplyr. Took me about an hour to figure out why this was happening. I fixed it by just ordering my column by values that weren't NAs, but it makes me nervous, especially when there are a lot of columns contributing to the calculation.