# Error when combining group_by, mutate and ifelse. Is it a bug? incompatible types, expecting a logical vector**

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having strange issues with dplyr and combination of group_by, mutate and ifelse. Consider the following data.frame

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  crawl.id = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1),
  group.id = factor(c("1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3")),
  hits.diff = c(NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA)
)
df1
#>   crawl.id group.id hits.diff
#> 1        1        1        NA
#> 2        1        2        NA
#> 3        2        2         0
#> 4        1        3        NA
#> 5        1        3        NA
#> 6        1        3        NA
```

When I use it the following code

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(group.id) %>% 
  mutate( hits.consumed = ifelse(hits.diff<=0,-hits.diff,0) )
```

For some reason I get

```
Error: incompatible types, expecting a logical vector**
```

However, removing either `group_by()` or `ifelse` everything works as expected:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate( hits.consumed = ifelse(hits.diff<=0,-hits.diff,0) )

crawl.id group.id hits.diff hits.consumed
1        1        1        NA            NA
2        1        2        NA            NA
3        2        2         0             0
4        1        3        NA            NA
5        1        3        NA            NA
6        1        3        NA            NA

df1 %>%
  group_by( group.id ) %>%
  mutate( hits.consumed = -hits.diff )

  crawl.id group.id hits.diff hits.consumed
1        1        1        NA            NA
2        1        2        NA            NA
3        2        2         0             0
4        1        3        NA            NA
5        1        3        NA            NA
6        1        3        NA            NA
```

Is it a bug or a feature? Can anyone replicate this?
What's so special about that specific combination of group_by, mutate and ifelse that makes it fail?

My own research led me here:
https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/464
which suggests that it should be fixed by now.

Comment: It fails for me too.   Looks like the group needs at least one non-NA values for this to work.  ie. `df1[2:3,] %>% group_by(group.id) %>% mutate(hits.consumed = ifelse(hits.diff <=0 , -hits.diff, 0))` worked

Comment: Yes, you are correct. `df1[1:3,]` fails yet `df1[2:3,]` works. It appears to be a reincarnation of that old dplyr issue 464.

Comment: You could file it as an issue

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Wrap it all in `as.numeric` to force the output format so the `NA`s, which are `logical` by default, don't override the class of the output variable:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(group.id) %>% 
  mutate( hits.consumed = as.numeric(ifelse(hits.diff<=0,-hits.diff,0)) )

#  crawl.id group.id hits.diff hits.consumed
#1        1        1        NA            NA
#2        1        2        NA            NA
#3        2        2         0             0
#4        1        3        NA            NA
#5        1        3        NA            NA
#6        1        3        NA            NA
```

Pretty sure this is the same issue as here: [Custom sum function in dplyr returns inconsistent results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351229/custom-sum-function-in-dplyr-returns-inconsistent-results/26351988) , as this result suggests:

```
out <- df1[1:2,] %>%  mutate( hits.consumed = ifelse(hits.diff <= 0, -hits.diff, 0))
class(out$hits.consumed)
#[1] "logical"
out <- df1[1:3,] %>%  mutate( hits.consumed = ifelse(hits.diff <= 0, -hits.diff, 0))
class(out$hits.consumed)
#[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Thanks! You are exactly right! I am browsing the issue #489 and @romainfrancois response -- it looks like this behavior was caused by inconsistent types returned by `ifelse` for some groups: logical and for some groups numeric. Your solution solves it by coercing it all into numeric before feeding into grouped mutate. Works perfectly!

Comment: Thank you. I have struggled all morning working on this very issue!

Comment: @thelatemail, Above query worked fine and gave me result for respective column but all the columns which has only alphabets are with no values and alphanumeric is as it is and numeric is as it is. How to get both the values of columns. Suggest me

Comment: @thelatemail, it worked fine with minor changes in my data.frame. Thank you :)