# Mutate and ifelse() fail becase of NA existence in column

Tags: r, dplyr

I've encountered an issue trying to create new column with `ifelse`. Quite similar question is this [dplyr error: strange issue when combining group_by, mutate and ifelse. Is it a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224719/dplyr-error-strange-issue-when-combining-group-by-mutate-and-ifelse-is-it-a-b)

```
set.seed(101)
time =sort(runif(10,0,10))  
group=rep(c(1,2),each=5)
az=c(sort(runif(5,-1,1),decreasing = T),sort(runif(5,-1,0.2),decreasing = T))

df <- data.frame(time,az,group)

#       time          az group
#1  0.4382482  0.86326886     1
#2  2.4985572  0.75959146     1
#3  3.0005483  0.46394519     1
#4  3.3346714  0.41374948     1
#5  3.7219838 -0.08975881     1
#6  5.4582855 -0.01547669     2
#7  5.8486663 -0.29161632     2
#8  6.2201196 -0.50599980     2
#9  6.5769040 -0.73105782     2
#10 7.0968402 -0.95366733     2
```

in the `df` I am trying to conditional mutate `clas` column. However, since there is `NA` inside of `sw_time` all `clas` column becomes also `NA` in which `group 1` should be `nrm` in usual way.

```
df1 <- df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(sw_time=abs(time[which(az<=0.8)[1]]-time[which(az>0)[1]]))%>%
  mutate(clas=as.numeric(ifelse(sw_time<3,"nrm","abn")))

Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
Groups: group [2]

        time          az group  sw_time  clas
       (dbl)       (dbl) (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl)
1  0.4382482  0.86326886     1 2.060309    NA
2  2.4985572  0.75959146     1 2.060309    NA
3  3.0005483  0.46394519     1 2.060309    NA
4  3.3346714  0.41374948     1 2.060309    NA
5  3.7219838 -0.08975881     1 2.060309    NA
6  5.4582855 -0.01547669     2       NA    NA
7  5.8486663 -0.29161632     2       NA    NA
8  6.2201196 -0.50599980     2       NA    NA
9  6.5769040 -0.73105782     2       NA    NA
10 7.0968402 -0.95366733     2       NA    NA
```

thanks in advance for your actions!

Comment: You are coerciing a character to numeric.  It will definitely result in NA.  Perhaps you need `clas = as.numeric(factor(ifelse(...`

Comment: @akrun yeap I just tried that but now `group 1` `clas` become 1 not `nrm`

Comment: In that case, you just remove the `as.numeric`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By converting `character` class to `numeric`, it will result in `NA`.  Instead, we may need to have a `factor` class that coerces to `numeric`

```
df %>%
    group_by(group)%>%
     mutate(sw_time=abs(time[which(az<=0.8)[1]]-time[which(az>0)[1]]),
            clas=as.integer(factor(ifelse(sw_time<3,"nrm","abn"))))
```

If we are only interested in getting 'nrm', 'abn', just remove the `as.integer(factor` wrapping

```
df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(sw_time=abs(time[which(az<=0.8)[1]]-time[which(az>0)[1]]),
          clas=ifelse(sw_time<3,"nrm","abn"))
#        time          az group  sw_time  clas
#       <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
#1  0.4382482  0.86326886     1 2.060309   nrm
#2  2.4985572  0.75959146     1 2.060309   nrm
#3  3.0005483  0.46394519     1 2.060309   nrm
#4  3.3346714  0.41374948     1 2.060309   nrm
#5  3.7219838 -0.08975881     1 2.060309   nrm
#6  5.4582855 -0.01547669     2       NA  <NA>
#7  5.8486663 -0.29161632     2       NA  <NA>
#8  6.2201196 -0.50599980     2       NA  <NA>
#9  6.5769040 -0.73105782     2       NA  <NA>
#10 7.0968402 -0.95366733     2       NA  <NA>
```

---

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c("sw_time", "clas") := {
           v1 <- abs(time[which(az <= 0.8)[1]] - time[which(az > 0)[1]])
          .(v1 , c("abn", "nrm")[(v1 < 3) + 1]) },
                      by = group]
```

---

If the final output does not involve 'nrm', 'abn', we don't need the `ifelse` part.  We can directly use `as.integer(sw_time <3)`

Comment: I couldn't catch directly use  `as.integer(sw_time<3)`. where is `nrm` and `abn` should be defined if there is no `ifelse` ?

Comment: @Alexander Please check the second code block.  The last one was when I was not sure about the expected output.  I thought you wanted to have a numeric index instead of 'nrm', 'abn'

Comment: the expected about is character like `nrm`. Actually when I run `df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(sw_time=abs(time[which(az<=0.8)[1]]-time[which(az>0)[1]]),
          clas=ifelse(sw_time<3,"nrm","abn"))`  I am getting error `Error: incompatible types, expecting a character vector`. actually this my original code right?

Comment: @Alexander I was using your example data.  Which version of `dplyr` you have ?  I am using `dplyr_0.5.0`

Comment: I was using `dplyr_0.4.3` and changed to `dplyr_0.5.0`. All fixed! thanks for your advice and great help! regards!