# Vectorising simple formatting function to handle vectors with NAs

Tags: r, function, format, vectorization, apply

I've a simple function that is used to format currency in desired manner across chart labels:

```
curr_fmt <- function(x) {
    f <- function(x) {
        if (is.numeric(x)) {
            if (x >= 1e4) {
                x <- x / 1e3
                paste0(intToUtf8(163), scales::comma(x), "K")
            } else {
                paste0(intToUtf8(163), scales::comma(x))
            }
        } else {
            x
        }
    }

    vf <- Vectorize(f, "x")
    vf(x)

}
```

## Examples

When applied to a numeric vector it produces desired results:

```
>> curr_fmt(c(1, 2e4, 3e4, 100))
[1] "£1"   "£20K" "£30K" "£100"
```

### Problem

The desired results are not produced if the vector contains **`NA`** values:

```
>> curr_fmt(c(1, 2e4, 3e4, 100, NA))
```

> Rerun with Debug  Error in `if (x >= 10000) {` : missing value where
>   `TRUE/FALSE` needed

The problem must be concerned with vectorisation as function **`f`** handles **`NA`** values in the desired way:

```
>> f(NA)
[1] NA
>> f(3e4)
[1] "£30K"
```

## Desired results

```
curr_fmt(c(1, 2e4, 3e4, 100, NA))
[1] "£1"   "£20K" "£30K" "£100" NA
```

- The returned object should be a character vector of length corresponding to the length of passed **`x`** vector with **`NA`** values returned as **`NA`** and currency values formatted as in the example.

---

## Notes:

- Please note that I'm not interested in `for-loop` solutions
- [mapply](/questions/tagged/mapply) / [sapply](/questions/tagged/sapply) based solutions will be accepted
- Ideally, I would like to see how to properly use [`Vectorize`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Vectorize.html) in this context
- The function does not have to handle strings

Comment: Perhaps you need `is.numeric(x) & !is.na(x)`

Comment: @akrun I was just going to post this as answer.

Comment: @akrun Correct! But why `is.numeric(NA)` returns `FALSE` shouldn't that make **`f`** jump to `else { x }` and return `NA`?

Comment: @Konrad you need `is.numeric(NA_real_)` otherwise, the `NA` by default will be different i.e. `class(NA)#[1] "logical"` `class(NA_real_)#
[1] "numeric"`

Comment: @Konrad if you test `is.numeric(NA)` it returns FALSE, but `is.numeric(inp[5])` is TRUE where `inp<-c(1, 2e4, 3e4, 100, NA)`. Why does it happen, it beats me.

Comment: @akrun Interesting, may be worth adding to your answer as an explanation. Also `f(NA)` works if not wrapped in `Vectorize` (as shown) but vectorisation forces the need for `!is.na(x)`.

Comment: @Tushar An atomic vector requires all elements to be of the same type, so `c(1, 2e4, 3e4, 100, NA)` coerces `NA` to `_NA_real`. This fits in with the data type hierarchy. The hierarchy can be found in the Value section of `?rbind` and some examples are provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21764262/4895725).

Comment: @lmo Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to change the `if` condition so that only non-NA values are used

```
curr_fmt <- function(x) {
    f <- function(x) {
        if (is.numeric(x) & !is.na(x)) { # changed here
            if (x >= 1e4) {
                x <- x / 1e3
                paste0(intToUtf8(163), scales::comma(x), "K")
            } else {
                paste0(intToUtf8(163), scales::comma(x))
            }
        } else {
            x
        }
    }

    vf <- Vectorize(f, "x")
    vf(x)

}

curr_fmt(c(1, 2e4, 3e4, 100, NA))
#[1] "£1"   "£20K" "£30K" "£100" NA    
curr_fmt(c(1, 2e4, 3e4, 100))
#[1] "£1"   "£20K" "£30K" "£100"
```

Answer (score 3):

Perfect situation for a decorator pattern:

```
robustify <- function(func)
{
    function(...)
    {
         z = (...)
         x = Filter(Negate(is.na), z)
         z[!is.na(z)] = func(x)
         z
    }
}

> robustify(curr_fmt)(c(1, 2e4, 3e4, NA, 23))
[1] "£1"   "£20K" "£30K" NA     "£23"
```

Asset: re-usable, fully functional, you do not need to modify the original function, just alter the behaviour if it's decorated.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and nice example with higher order functions.

Comment: This is pretty cool. One simplification: `which(!is.na(z))` could be `!is.na(z)`.

Answer (score 3):

Now that akrun's answer was accepted it no longer matters, but here's a vectorized solution with no need for `if/else`.

```
curr_fmt2 <- function(x){
    y <- character(length(x))
    isna <- is.na(x)
    isnum <- is.numeric(x)
    y[isna] <- NA
    y[!isna & !isnum] <- x[!isna & !isnum]
    inx <- !isna & isnum & x < 1e4
    y[inx] <- paste0(intToUtf8(163), scales::comma(x[inx]))
    inx <- !isna & isnum & x >= 1e4
    x <- x / 1e3
    y[inx] <- paste0(intToUtf8(163), scales::comma(x[inx]), "K")
    y
}

x1 <- c(1, 2e4, 3e4, 100)
x2 <- c(1, 2e4, 3e4, 100, NA)

curr_fmt2(x1)
[1] "£1"   "£20K" "£30K" "£100"
curr_fmt2(x2)
[1] "£1"   "£20K" "£30K" "£100" NA
```